# Чи є український відповідник до слова "флаєр"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Всюди роздають **флаєри**. Розумію, що це певна рекламка якогось продукту, однак хочеться переконатися у тому, що саме термін означає і чи містить власне питомі відповідники. Адже зараз запозичені слова масово увійшли у вжиток, проте мені все ж хочеться використовувати питомі.

P. S. : У **[СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/flajer)** цього слова взагалі не подають, оскільки, ймовірно, до нас прийшло зовсім недавно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На [Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%94%D1%80)) знаходимо:

> **Флаєр** — це форма паперової реклами, призначеної для широкого розповсюдження. Зазвичай публікується або розповсюджується в публічному місці, роздається людям або надсилається поштою. У 2010 роках флаєри варіюються від недорогих копіюваних листівок до дорогих, глянцевих, повнокольорових циркулярів.
>
> **Флаєр** також можна назвати *флієр, циркуляр, рекламний листок (метелик), брошура, плакат, літ (літературою), щотижневе оголошення, каталог або листівка…*

Також пропонують вживати слово [**літунець**](http://kopychyntsi.com.ua/suspilstvo/slovnychok-novotvirnychok-vid-iurka-zelenogo.html).

Цікаві українські відповідники знаходимо також на сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/flaier): **літунець, листівка, роздатка, літайчик, роздайчик, летючка.**